# Angular-Material styles not loading in single-spa app

Tags: angular, angular-material, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I am trying to create a simple Angular Application and run it as a Microfrontend in single-spa. In the Angular App I want to add Angular-Material. The problem is, that the Material Styles are loaded in the "standalone" app without single-spa but not when I use single-spa.

I created a simple Angular App and added the latest Material version to it using "ng add @angular/material". I then added single-spa to that app using this tutorial https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/#installation.

This is the HTML I added to the Angular App:
`<mat-toolbar> <button class="homeButton" mat-button routerLink="." color="primary"> <mat-icon id="homeButtonIcon">map</mat-icon> Routefinder </button> </mat-toolbar>`

And these are my imports in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmptyRouteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

When I add the App as a Microfrontend to single-spa it is rendered like this (console doesn't show errors):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5CDO.png)

This is the relevant part of my index.ejs and root config:

```
 <script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "single-spa": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.9.0/lib/system/single-spa.min.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.9.0/lib/system/single-spa.min.js" as="script">

  <% if (isLocal) { %>
  <script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "@abc/root-config": "//localhost:9000/root-config.js",
    "@abc/navbar": "http://localhost:8001/main.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <% } %>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zone.js@0.11.3/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
```

```
registerApplication({
  name: "@abc/navbar",
  app: () => System.import("http://localhost:8001/main.js"),
  activeWhen: ["/"],
});
```

Comment: Hello.  Because I am no Angular developer, I cannot really give you a solid answer.  What I **can** give you is a link to the official single-spa documentation regarding CSS:  [Click me](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-css).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I figured out, that when I included the CSS in the single-spa index.ejs, then the styles load correctly. But not when I include the CSS in the Microfrontend. For now I load the styles, in my case indigo-pink, in the styleguide. Meaning I load it as a global style like this: @import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@angular/material@15.2.8/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css");
I know this is not the proper way to do it so I am still searching for a solution.

Comment: So nothing in the official documentation shed a light about how to mount/unmount CSS along with the mife?  :-( I have noticed that many people have issues with single-spa, many of which comes from the use of `create-single-spa`, in my opinion.  I am mounting a series of articles about single-spa and how to use it outside of `create-single-spa`.